# using gabor filter in tensorflow , or any other filter instead of default one

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, deep-learning, convolution

I want to use gabor filter in my CNN. Using convolution2d function how can I change it to conv input images to my gabor filters, not default Gaussian ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some code that you can use as a guide to apply a constant (non-learned) Gabor filter created using the OpenCV library :

```
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2

# Create a 3x3 Gabor filter
params = {'ksize':(3, 3), 'sigma':1.0, 'theta': 0, 'lambd':15.0, 'gamma':0.02}
filter = cv2.getGaborKernel(**params)
# make the filter to have 4 dimensions.
filter = tf.expand_dims(filter, 2)
filter = tf.expand_dims(filter, 3)

# Apply the filter on `image`
answer = tf.conv2d(image, filter, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
```

Comment: Thanx . it helps me alot

Comment: there is small problem . it giving error when i am using it as : ValueError: Shape must be rank 4 but is rank 2 for 'LeviHassner/Conv2D' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [128,227,227,3], [5,5].                          
I think i should change gabor filter from 2 d to 4 d but how? @keveman

Comment: Updated the code to show how to expand the dimensions of `filter`. In your case, since the input image has 3 dimensions, you probably want to make 3 calls to `getGaborKernel` and concatenate the results.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the function to do the same :

```
def gabor_filtering(image) :
   """
   Using Gabor Filters to repair
   motion blurriness in an image.
   """
   theta = [0, 45, 90, 135]
   filtered_images = []
   sharpen_kernel = np.array([[-1,-1,-1], [-1,9,-1], [-1,-1,-1]])
   for th in theta :
      kernel = cv2.getGaborKernel(ksize = (3, 3), sigma = 5, lambd = 5, theta = th, 
               gamma = 0.25)
      kernel = tf.expand_dims(kernel, 0)
      kernel = tf.expand_dims(kernel, 0)
      kernel = tf.cast(kernel, tf.float32)
      filtered_images.append(tf.nn.conv2d(image, kernel, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], 
                             padding='SAME'))
   final_img = tf.math.maximum(tf.math.maximum(filtered_images[0], 
   filtered_images[1]), tf.math.maximum(filtered_images[2], filtered_images[3]))

   #Sharpening the image
   sharpen_kernel = tf.expand_dims(sharpen_kernel, 0)
   sharpen_kernel = tf.expand_dims(sharpen_kernel, 0)
   sharpen_kernel = tf.cast(sharpen_kernel, tf.float32)
   return tf.nn.conv2d(final_img, sharpen_kernel, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], 
                       padding='SAME')
```

Here, i am using Gabor filters to treat motion blurriness in an image. I am using 4 different kernel with different theta values. I have kept rest of the parameters same but you can change them as per your need.

After applying 4 kernels, i am taking pixel-wise maximum of all the 4 filtered images. This strengthens the edges and smoothens none-edge parts. In the end i am sharpening the image.

Hope this helps :)